iOS universal link how to conditional open web or App
I have two apps, where one can open the other via a universal link.
However, I'd like to modify the process so that the first time a user clicks the link, it directs them to a language selection page on a mobile website. After they choose a language, the second app should launch. Once the language is selected, I want to bypass the language selection page on subsequent clicks, and just open the second app directly. Is this feasible?

I might be missing summat, but I think it's not possible. As an alternative, consider opening the web site in a web view inside your app.
